# In Grails, how do I combine the head tags of a view and a template?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm creating a Grails plugin which has a template. The idea is that the developer can just call  and get all of the rendering functionality that I build in the template.

The issue I'm facing has to do with the head tags of both the view and the template. Currently, the template in the plugin has a `<head>` tag with multiple JS files. If the developer of another Grails project decides to use `<g:render/>`and call my template, the head tag of the view is getting replaced by the head tag of the template.

Is there any way to combine the two? Essentially, if view.gsp has a head tag and my own template (pulled in from another plugin) has a head tag, I want them to be combined.

Answer (score 1):

From this 
http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/guide/theWebLayer.html#layouts

It shows that you can have the head tag of a template and view exists as long as the :

```
<g:layoutHead />
```

is in the head of the template to load the head of the view

> 8.2.4 Layouts with Sitemesh
>
> Creating Layouts
>   Grails leverages Sitemesh, a decorator engine, to support view layouts. Layouts are located in the `grails-app/views/layouts` directory. A typical

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title><g:layoutTitle default="An example decorator" /></title>
        <g:layoutHead />
    </head>
    <body onload="${pageProperty(name:'body.onload')}">
        <div class="menu"><!--my common menu goes here--></div>
        <div class="body">
            <g:layoutBody />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> The key elements are the `layoutHead, layoutTitle and layoutBody` tag invocations:

```
layoutTitle - outputs the target page's title
layoutHead - outputs the target page's head tag contents
layoutBody - outputs the target page's body tag contents
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe this only works if the view has a meta tag which defined the layout. That is, it has `<meta name="layout" content="myLayout" />`.  
However, in my situation, I'm not setting the template as the layout but rather just calling it directly with `<g:render />`

Comment: Since that's the case you can't load the head from that template into the view. The only way to so that is to use the meta tag configuration which will use the sitemesh layout.